# ProgressBar in ViewBinder hast strange values

Tags: android, android-listview, android-viewbinder

I have a `SimpleAdapter` with a `ViewBinder`. The `ViewBinder` binds some `TextViews` and a `ProgressBar`. The `TextView` works fine but when I scroll the list back I get weird values for the `ProgressBar`. Why does this happens

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found it out. It happens because the data binder loads dynamically. I had to revoke my algorithms. I hope if someone else encounters this problem my answer will help.